# Foreign key entity framework asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho Minha Tabela Conserto e ConsertoDetalhes e estou recebendo a seguinte msg quando tento atualizar minha migration:
"A introdução da restrição FOREIGN KEY 'FK_dbo.ConsertoDetalhes_dbo.Pecas_PecasId' 
na tabela 'ConsertoDetalhes' pode causar ciclos ou vários caminhos em cascata. Especifique ON DELETE NO ACTION ou ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 ou modifique outras restrições FOREIGN KEY.
Não foi possível criar a restrição ou o índice. Consulte os erros anteriores."

```
    public class Conserto
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }
    public string NomeFuncionario { get; set; }
    public string NomePeca {get;set;}
    public string DescricaoDefeito { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoSolucao { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorMaoObra { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorTotalConserto { get; set; }
    public int PecasId { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("PecasId")]
    public virtual Pecas Pecas { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FuncionarioId")]
    public virtual Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }

}
```

ConserDetalhes

```
    public class ConsertoDetalhes
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ConsertoId { get; set; }
    public int PecasId { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ConsertoId")]
    public virtual Conserto  Conserto { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PecasId")]
    public virtual Pecas Pecas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: você mesmo que montou esse modelo ? você precisar mesmo dos ( public int PecasId { get; set; } ... public int ClienteId { get; set; } ...  public int FuncionarioId { get; set; } ... e criar  public virtual Pecas Pecas { get; set; } ?

Comment: sim porque quando estou criando, eu preciso ter acesso a lista de peças,funcionario e cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está colocando ForeignKey "PecasId" nas duas classes (que já estão relacionadas)por isto o migration está reclamando de referência circular, remova de uma das classes preferencialmente da classe Conserto.

Comment: O problema que se eu remover do conserto eu não vou ter acesso a lista de peça.

Comment: Pelo detalhamento da classe Conserto você não consegue? Já que exite uma relação entre as duas.

Comment: Quando estou na View Criar ordem de servico eu preciso ter acesso a lista de peças,lista de cliente e lista de funcionarios. Em ConsertoDetalhes eu preciso ter acesso também a lista de Id das Peças e o id do Conserto, então eu preciso de FK em ambos para ter acesso ao que preciso